# How to compare if two URLs are the same in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, url

I want to check if URLs are the same but, these ones should be consider the same:

- if they are have same parameters but in different orders
- they are the some no matter they start with http, https or without it

for example this should be the same:

- http://www.example.com/?foo=bar&bar=foo
- http://www.example.com/?bar=foo&foo=bar

Comment: Could you add code that you have tried so far?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php - would be a good start

Comment: Share url and param examples ?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For example these should be the same:

www.example.com/?foo=bar&bar=foo
http://www.example.com/?foo=bar&bar=foo
http://www.example.com/?bar=foo&foo=bar

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what is meant. But, if by reading between-the-lines, you just want to make sure that both 'foo' and 'bar' are set in the url, you should try isset:

```
if(isset($_GET['foo']) && isset($_GET['bar'])){
  //do stuff for true
}
else {
  //do stuff if not
}
```